# Huge Files Uploading in asp.net Video Starter Kit

Tags: asp.net, starter-kits

I am using Video started Kit, First I used to upload videos/audios on local directory and It was uploading, Now I have implemented to upload files on Amazon S3 server. 
Because of this files takes too much time in uploading and then final validation(that green progress bar). 
I am having problem with some audio files(for eg If i upload file size approx 12MB), It takes too much time in validation then after long time, It redirects to audio/confirm.aspx but there It shows success message only and no Form to enter data.Same issue with videos, I tried uploading files around 1MB,sometimes they get uploaded some times not. 
I have this set in my web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="5000" maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" />
```

executionTimeout was 3600, I increased it but still same issue. What else should I have to do